# Set theory , the existence of a solution not using linear algebra .

Tags: elementary-set-theory

hy I hope everyone is having a good day .  , I post this problem for aiming to discuss it : let $n\geq 1$ a positive integer , and $(X_{i})_{i\in [[1,n+1]]}$  a family of non empty sets of $[[1,n]]$ , Does there exist two subsets $I$ and $J$ such that $I\cap J$ is empty   of $[[1,n+1]]$ such that : 
$ \cup_{i \in I} X_{i} = \cup_{j \in J} X_{j}~~ ? $  I know a solution of this using linear algebra , and wonder if we can solve it , without using linear algebra . Any suggestion is welcome . Thank you ,

Comment: $I=J=\emptyset$?

Comment: What exactly is used from "linear algebra" in your solution?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen $I$ and $J$ need to be non empty

Comment: @DietrichBurde consider the $n\times n+1$ matrix $M$ such that $M_{i,j}=1$ if $i\in X_{j}$ , $0$ else , then notice that $KerM$ is non zero and we can construct $I$ and $J$ from that .